# Ship [shipping] to /dev/null

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

We have [six questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shipping) tagged [shipping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shipping). The tag has no description and there seems to be no clear usage for it.

I would like to remove it completely.

Opinions please.

Comment: Go for it. It seems to be a meta tag.

Comment: 1) My opinion is that the title is great! 2) A couple of the questions use "shipping" as decoration and those should have the tag removed regardless.  Most are about preparing a computer for safely transporting it, which seems like a good subject for a tag, but one that is less meta.

Comment: Maybe [computer-transport-prep] as the main tag and make [shipping] a synonym since that's the term people think of.  BTW, I removed the tag from the two questions with irrelevant usage.

Comment: BTW, we have a [travel] tag that is also meta.  I cleaned up the tags that were useless decoration, but the 5 remaining would fit under the same tag as the remaining [shipping] questions.

Comment: I'm disappointed none of those questions involves GNU/Linux slash fiction.

Answer (score 2):

[shipped](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shipped) out to /dev/null/ as requested